# How can I perform this task in SQL Server 2008 without using a cursor?

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor

I wrote this SQL Server 2008 code to call a stored proc on every value in a temp table.  Unfortunately, there were over 660K values in the temp table, so executing it caused an 'Out of memory' exception.  Is there a way to perform the same task WITHOUT the use of a cursor?:

```
DECLARE @cons_to_delete uniqueidentifier

DECLARE @DeleteCursor CURSOR 
SET @DeleteCursor = CURSOR FOR
  SELECT consumer_uuid FROM tmp_UuidsOfClientsToDELETE



 OPEN @DeleteCursor
    FETCH NEXT From @DeleteCursor
    INTO @cons_to_delete
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
      exec sp_DeleteConsumer @cons_to_delete
      FETCH NEXT FROM @DeleteCursor
    END
    CLOSE @DeleteCursor
    DEALLOCATE @DeleteCursor
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Post the code for the stored procedure

Comment: I cannot see how the above would cause am OOM, unless there is something really bad inside the stored proc.  Which means it has nothing to do with having a cursor.  As @MartinSmith says above, post the contents of the stored proc.

Comment: @Greg 660,000 `x rows affected` messages in management studio could do it. In which case `set nocount on` would resolve that particular issue but likely there's a better way without the cursor anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If [Management Studio is giving you a Out of Memory Exception](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2874903), then it is probably because your stored procedure is outputting something and sending too much data to your client.  I don't think it is the cursor that is causing the error message from your client.

Answering your question though... in order to eliminate the need for the cursor would entail rewriting the stored procedure so that it used set based logic.  So for example if your procedure `sp_DeleteConsumer` looked like this:

```
delete ConsumerTable
where ConsumerID = @cons_to_delete
```

You could either join the `ConsumerTable` directly to your temp table or pass a table valued parameter and change the statement to:

```
delete ConsumerTable
from ConsumerTable
join tmp_UuidsOfClientsToDELETE
on ConsumerTable.ConsumerID = tmp_UuidsOfClientsToDELETE.consumer_uuid
```

Comment: The sproc called in this case is complex.  It does some checking on whether there are any conditions in the database that would PREVENT the record from being deleted.  If the record can be deleted, it also deletes child records from lots of other tables.  But it only returns 2 integers.  

The reason I wanted to use this sproc is so I wouldn't have to rethink all the logic it uses.  So I think the short answer to my question is, there's not a simple way to redo this task without a cursor.  Would you agree?

Comment: There is no way to turn it into set based logic with that procedure as it is... correct.  If that procedure is returning a result set though, even if it's just a couple of integers, that is probably what is crashing your client while trying to handle over a half million result sets returned.